# Set a for loop to loop through untill null byte is detected

Tags: c++

I have a question about a string in C++. As per below code, I would like to know where will the loops stop at. Will it take the null in index 3 or index 4?

```
#include <cstdio>

int main ( ) {

  char name [20] = "Foo";

  name [4] = '\0';

  for (int i = 0; name[i] != '\0'; i++) {

       printf("This is the value of i so far in the loop : %d \n",i);
  }

  printf("This is the value of i : %d \n",i);

 return 0;

}
```

the reason I am asking this is,I don't understand why in my homework they gave us something like this. Is there any reason to make '\0' in index 4?

Comment: I just don't understand why in my homework they gave us something like this. Is there any reason to make '\0' in index 4?

Comment: No, they want you to realize that a string definition ends with `\0`

Comment: @juergen d : The compiler automatically puts a `'\0'` after "Foo".

Comment: I know that. but shouldn't it end but at index 3? why 4?

Comment: It ends with 3! They just put another end charachter there to confuse you and make you think about it.

Comment: May be your teacher had started counting from 1..... ;)...

Comment: Thank you for all of your comments... I got it now :)

Comment: Maybe your teacher meant name[4] to become something other than `\0`.

Comment: no, I just check and this what he said. '\0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Foo" is actually {'F','o','o','\0'}, and fits index 0,1,2,3.
Index 4 up to 19 are default initialized (hence 0-ed). And index 4 is assigned later with '\0'.

The loop ends when the first '\0' is matched, so that value 0,1,2 are printed.
Out of the loop `i` shold ... ahem .. be undefined! (it is declared inside the loop scope), but if your compiler didn't clean up you most likely will print 3.

A typycal example of C++ (note `#include<cstdio>`, but no std never referenced...) taught by a C instructed teacher.
Give my congrats to him!

Comment: "Index 4 up to 19 are uninitialized". I disagree. C++2003, 8.5.1/7 says: "If there are fewer initializers in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member not
explicitly initialized shall be value-initialized."

Comment: +1 for snide comment about bad C++ teachers. To be clear, this program is "ill-formed" as that term is defined in C++ 2003, due to the lack of `std::`.

Comment: @Rob: you're right: the char::char() should be used to produce the value, hence they should be all 0. Unfortunately I saw many compiler not doing that, so I usually don't rely on it.

Comment: And +1 for noticing that `i` is undefined after the loop. It shouldn't even compile!

Comment: @MrLister: yes, g++ says "use -permissve", in fact relaxing the ISO compliancy

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any reason to make '\0' in index 4?

Absolutely none.

This line:

```
char name [20] = "Foo";
```

Initializes the array as follows:

```
name[0] <-- 'F'    First char of "Foo"
name[1] <-- 'o'    Second char of "Foo"
name[2] <-- 'o'    Third char of "Foo"
name[3] <-- '\0'   Fourth char of "Foo"
name[4..19] <-- 0  Extra spaces in array get zero-filled
```

So, this line:

```
  name [4] = '\0';
```

writes a zero to a location *already guaranteed to be zero*.

So, there is a zero at index 3 (it is the final char in "Foo"). There is a zero in all of the locations 4-19 (since the initializer is smaller than the array). And, redundantly, there is a zero written to index 4.

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be 3:

```
name[0]='F' name[1]='o' name[2]='o' name[3]='\0' name[4]='\0'
```